# Lombok @Builder inheritance workaround

Tags: java, lombok

Lombok @Builder doesn't work for inheritance use cases:

For example

```
class Foo{
 protected int xyz1;
 .....
 protected String xyz7;
}


class Bar extends Foo{

}
```

For given use case Lombok will not be able to generate methods to set value of parameter defined in Foo class.

A workaround for this is:

1. Manual creating constructor of Bar.
2. Putting a Builder annotation on that constructor.

Is there a better workaround ?

Comment: In my opinion this is a fine solution.  How would you imagine it should work?

Answer (score 57):

Lombok has introduced experimental features with version: 1.18.2 for inheritance issues faced with Builder annotation, and can be resolved with @SuperBuilder annotation as below.

```
@SuperBuilder
public class ParentClass {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
}

@SuperBuilder
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    private final String c;
}
```

Now, one can use Builder class as below (that was not possible with @Builder annotation)

```
ChildClass.builder().a("testA").b("testB").c("testC").build();
```

Comment: Idea 2018.1 shows error in editor, but build and run is OK.

Comment: Perfect! And works with more than one layer of inheritance. Thank you!

Comment: this doesn't work for me using lombok 1.18.20
I foud this alternative https://blog.knoldus.com/how-to-deal-with-inheritance-while-using-lombok-builder/

Answer (score 21):

**I leave this here for reference, as other answers demonstrate there is now (not at the time this answer was posted) a @SuperBuilder feature available now in the library which seems more fitting.**

It´s a bit hidden, but people have had this question before, see:

https://reinhard.codes/2015/09/16/lomboks-builder-annotation-and-inheritance/

To summarise the blog post

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
  private String a;
}

public class Child extends Parent {

  private String b;

  @Builder
  private Child(String a, String b){
    super(a);
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Would allow you to use

```
Child.builder().a("testA").b("testB").build()
```

Comment: well don't blame me! that's as much support as there is unless somebody improves the library

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with more than one layer of inheritance. But @Anamika's answer with `@SuperBuilder` worked for me.

Comment: I moved my edit comment to the top of the answer, this answer is older than the @SuperBuilder feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to this problem currently in the works. Check the progress here: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/1337